# How to get matches for some words in a list from another list?

Tags: python, function, for-loop, match, difflib

I have two lists, I want to compare one list with the other and get all the close matches as output for each word.

For example:

```
a = ['apple','python','ice-cream']
b = ['aaple','aple','phython','icecream','cat','dog','cell']
```

so when I pass the list 'a' i need to get 'aaple','aple','phython','icecream' as outputs from 'b'.

I used difflib.get_close_matches(word,pattern), but couldn't pass the whole list in one of the inputs.

```
difflib.get_close_matches('apple',b)

OUTPUT:
['aaple','aple']
```

How can I pass the whole list instead of just a single word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will create a list with all the close words:

```
import difflib
diff_words = []
for word in a:
    diff_words += difflib.get_close_matches(word, b)
print(diff_words)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested list comprehension, such as:

```
[close_match for word in a for close_match in difflib.get_close_matches(word, b)]
```